# Extract text after a symbol in R

Tags: regex, r, text-mining, extract

```
sample1 = read.csv("pirate.csv")
sample1[,7] 
[1] >>xyz>>hello>>mate 1
[2] >>xyz>>hello>>mate 2
[3] >>xyz>>mate 3
[4] >>xyz>>mate 4
[5] >>xyz>>hello>>mate 5
[6] >>xyz>>hello>>mate 6
```

I have to extract and create an array which contains all the words after last `>>`.

How to do this?

Also, How can I extract (a) o qwerty, (b) mate1 and (c) pirate1 in different variables from the following string

```
p= '>>xyz- o qwerty>>hello>>mate1>>sole pirate1'
```

Thanks

Comment: why is there an `r` tag. do you need it in `r` as well as excel?

Comment: yes, I have to extract a column from an excel file to r in a vector form

Comment: See `read.csv` the arguments header and nrows. This should get you started with reading. There are a lot of questions on SO about this.

Comment: Do you want to always extract the last word or just the word after 'ahoy'?

Comment: it's not the last word or the word after ahoy...my motive is to extract specific words in a string like extracting "stuff data" from the string
">>hello1>>hola1>>ahoy xyz stuff data mate1"

Comment: That is why is best to use reproducible example. Have a look at `read.csv` (after you save your excel file as .csv) and use `dput` in `r` to produce an example. Also have a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
x <- c('>>xyz>>hello>>mate 1', '>>xyz>>hello>>mate 2', '>>xyz>>mate 3', ' >>xyz>>mate 4' ,'>>xyz>>hello>>mate 5')
sub('.*>>', '', x)
#[1] "mate 1" "mate 2" "mate 3" "mate 4" "mate 5"
```

Comment: you are giving each and every row name of column 7 in the x vector. 

1) How can I pass the whole column in the vector(as these are only 6 rows but I am dealing with more than 100 rows)

2) I also want to extract text between two specific symbols for eg.

>>xyz-qwerty>>hello>>mate1>>pirate1

in above I want to extract qwerty and hello in two separate variables. Please help me with that.

Thanks

Comment: well, to select the individual column then replace `x` with `sample1$...` or `sample1[,7]`. For extracting other terms you will need to update your question and give some more details about it.

Comment: How about something like: `gsub('.* ', "", unlist(strsplit(p, '>>')))` ?

Comment: it is giving me result like this

[""    ""    ""   "pirate1"]

Comment: It should give you this: `[1] ""        "qwerty"  "hello"   "mate1"   "pirate1"`

Comment: can also use `str_replace_all(x, ".*>>","")`

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you already read that stuff into an R data frame, you can use `stringr` package as follows:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df$mystring, '\\S+$')
```

For example, if you have string like this:

```
s <- '>>hello1>>hola1>>ahoy mate1'
```

You get:

```
str_extract(s, '\\S+$')
[1] "mate1"
```

Comment: or simply `sub('.* ', '', s)` but I think his problem has to do with also importing data in R...

Comment: Yeah. Agree. I lead people to packages that are versatile so they can do more with them as needed for different problems.

Comment: `all the words after last >>` in your example should be `ahoy mate1`