# R - Find & Extract string from right

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have this vector:

```
data <- structure(1:5, .Label = c("AVE_prQD_AFR_p10", "PER_prVD_DSR_p9", "PA_prSX_AR_p8", 
"prAV_AES_p7", "prGR_AXXR_p6", "prQW_AWAR_p5"), class = "factor")

  V1
1 "AVE_prQD_AFR_p10"
2 "PER_prVD_DSR_p9"
3 "PA_prS_X_AR_p8"
4 "prAV_AES_p7"
5 "prGR_AXXR_p6"
```

I'm trying to extract the latest characters to the right, specifically from the latest `_` to the end of the string. I don't know how many `_` are in each string, but I do know that there always will be at least one, and always will be one `_` before the part of the string I need. To give you an example:

```
"any_random_string_0" # "0" is the string I need
"any_random_string_f20" # "f20" is the string I need
"any_random_string_p3" # "p3" is the string I need
```

As you could infer from the example above, the last part of the string will always start with `_`, followed by a `p`, `f` or `0`, and then will end the string with a number from 1 to 99" (except if its 0):

```
"_" + "f" or "p" or "0" + "1" to "99"
```

There is NEVER gonna be something after the number. Hence, the full string ends with the string I need. So, looking for a solution I was trying to find (unsuccessfully) some function that search `_` **from the right**.

Plus, I need to transform that string given these conditions:

- If the string has `p`, multiply the number by `-1`
- If the string has `f`, the number is positive
- If the string is `_0`, give it `0`.

This is my attempt, it works, but only with a fixed position of `_` and with a number from 0 to 9.

```
function(some_vector_string){
  result <- stringr::str_sub(some_vector_string, -2,-2) %>% 
    {ifelse(. == "p",
            as.numeric(stringr::str_sub(some_vector_string, -1,-1))*-1,
            ifelse(. == "f",
                   as.numeric(stringr::str_sub(some_vector_string, -1,-1))*1,
                   ifelse(.=="_", 0, -100)))}
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: Why not split the string by "_" and take the last element?

Comment: Yep, pretty sure this has been answered here before a few times. I'll hunt for the duplicate, but I think you can just destroy everything up to the last `_` like `sub(".+_", "", data)`

Comment: I hope you find the duplicate thelatemail because I found none xD. @LMc didn't come to my mind. I will try that one.

Comment: For the first part of the question maybe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774086/extracting-text-after-last-period-in-string or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943533/r-get-last-element-from-str-split or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051288/extract-text-after-a-symbol-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base `R` something like:

```
a <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(data), "_"), function(x) rev(x)[1])

ifelse(startsWith(a, "0"), 0, c(-1, 1)[startsWith("p", a) + 1] * as.numeric(gsub("\\D*", "", a)))
[1] -10  -9  -8  -7  -6
```

Or using tidyverse libraries:

```
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

n <- setNames(c(0, -1, 1), c("0", "p", "f"))

map_dbl(str_remove(data, ".*_"), ~ n[substr(., 1, 1)] * parse_number(.))

[1] -10  -9  -8  -7  -6
```

---

**How it works**

1. `stringr::str_remove(data, ".*_")`

As mentioned in the comments by @thelatemail `.*` is a *greedy* regular expression that takes zero or more (`*`) of any character (`.`). So this removed everything up until the **last** underscore, hence it's greedy:

```
str_remove("A_B_C_D", ".*_")
[1] "D"
```

This is opposed to *ungreedy* (`?`), which does not try to match as much as possible:

```
str_remove("A_B_C_D", ".*?_")
[1] "B_C_D"
```

2. `purrr::map_dbl`

This function iterates over a list or atomic vector and outputs an atomic vector of type double, hence the `_dbl`.

The `~` is a lambda/purrr style syntax. Up until `R` 4.1.0 this would be be written in base `R` as: `function(x) n[substr(x, 1, 1)] * parse_number(x)`. It's just a cleaner, easier-to-read, less wordy way of applying an anonymous function (ie a function that has not been assigned to a name). This is a common syntactic style in the tidyverse. Here the `x` argument of the function is replaced by the dot notation `.`.

3. `n[substr(., 1, 1)] * parse_number(.)`

`substr(., 1, 1)` takes the first character of the parsed string:

```
substr("f20", 1,1 )
[1] "f"
```

Then it looks up that first character in the named vector `n` to return the value you specified in the question, which is one in the case when the letter is `"f"`:

```
n["f"]
f 
1
```

`readr::parse_number` extracts all the digits from a string and returns it as numeric:

```
readr::parse_number("f20")
[1] 20
```

These two values are multiplied and returned as an element in the double atomic vector output.

Note: this works when the suffix is `"0"` because the result of this operation is `0*0`:

```
substr("0",1 ,1)
[1] "0"

n["0"]
0 
0 

parse_number("0")
[1] 0

n[substr("0", 1, 1)] * parse_number("0")
0 
0
```

You'll notice this output is technically a named vector with `"0"` being the name and the value being `0`; however, this is coerced to a double vector by `map_dbl`.

Comment: Why not use the named vector logic in base R too? `n[substr(a, 1, 1)] * as.numeric(gsub("\\D*", "", a))` instead of `ifelse`

Comment: It worked! Could you explain a little bit the logic? Specifically, what does, ´map_dbl´, the string ´.*_´, the symbol ´~´, and the multiplication of ´parse_number(.)´ and its dot do? (I know the dot from the pipe operator and the ´~´ sign for regression formulas, but nothing else). Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Great! Glad it worked. I've updated my answer with some additional explanation. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with rebus and this is what I get:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rebus)
library(stringr)
data <- structure(1:5, .Label = c("AVE_prQD_AFR_p10", "PER_prVD_DSR_p9", "PA_prSX_AR_p8", 
                                      "prAV_AES_p7", "prGR_AXXR_p6", "prQW_AWAR_p5"), class = "factor")
    
#rebus END regex lets you narrow the search to the last part of the string
chars <-
    str_extract(data , rebus::or(ANY_CHAR %R% one_or_more(DGT) %R% END, '0' %R% END)) 
    
    ##fabricate the conditions
    #map_dbl is also an option to avoid returning a list
numbers <-
    map(chars, ~
            if(str_sub(.x,1 ,1) == 'p'){
                as.numeric(str_extract(.x, one_or_more(DGT))) * -1
            } else{
                if (str_sub(.x,1 ,1) == 'f'){
                    as.numeric(str_extract(.x, one_or_more(DGT)))
                } else {
                    0
                }
                
        })
    
print(numbers)
``
```

Answer (score 1):

**Data**:

```
data <- data.frame(V1 = c("AVE_prQD_AFR_p10", "PER_prVD_DSR_p9", "PA_prSX_AR_p8", 
                     "prAV_AES_p7", "prGR_AXXR_p6", "prQW_AWAR_p5",
                     "AVE_prQD_AFR_f10", "PER_prVD_DSR_f9", "PA_prSX_AR_f8", 
                     "prAV_AES_f7", "prGR_AXXR_f6", "prQW_AWAR_f5",
                     "AVE_prQD_AFR_0", "PER_prVD_DSR_0", "PA_prSX_AR_0", 
                     "prAV_AES_0", "prGR_AXXR_0", "prQW_AWAR_0"))
```

***Method 1***

We can work on it as follows:

1. Separate the first portion (containing alphanumeric characters and at least 1 "_") and the second portion (containing only alphanumeric characters) into `V2` and `V3` respectively
2. Extract only numeric values from `V3` to obtain `V4`
3. If `V3` contains "p", obtain `V5` by taking `V4*-1`. Others remain the same

**Code**:

```
data %>% 
  tidyr::extract(V1, c("V2", "V3"), "([[:alnum:]_]+)_([[:alnum:]]+)$", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(V4 = readr::parse_number(V3),
         v5 = case_when(stringr::str_detect(V3, "p") ~ V4*-1,
                        TRUE ~ V4))
```

***Method 2***

Or perhaps, instead of splitting the string into 2 (as seen in Method 1), we may just extract the portion of interest and work from there.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(V2 = stringr::str_extract(V1, "[pf]?\\d{1,2}$"),
         V3 = readr::parse_number(V2),
         v4 = case_when(stringr::str_detect(V2, "p") ~ V3*-1,
                        TRUE ~ V3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for extracting all ending digits and multiply with -1, if they start with an f (positive numbers are ok anyway and 0 has no sign):

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(1:8, .Label = c("AVE_prQD_AFR_p10", "PER_prVD_DSR_p9", "PA_prSX_AR_p8", 
                              "prAV_AES_p7", "prGR_AXXR_p6", "prQW_AWAR_p5",
                              "prQW_AWAR_0", "prQW_AWAR_f5"), class = "factor")

data %>%
  enframe(name = NULL, value = "V1") %>% # create tibble from vector
  mutate(want = as.numeric(str_extract(V1, "\\d+$")) * if_else(str_detect(V1, "_f\\d+$"), -1, 1))

#V1                want
#<fct>            <dbl>
#  1 AVE_prQD_AFR_p10    10
#2 PER_prVD_DSR_p9      9
#3 PA_prSX_AR_p8        8
#4 prAV_AES_p7          7
#5 prGR_AXXR_p6         6
#6 prQW_AWAR_p5         5
#7 prQW_AWAR_0          0
#8 prQW_AWAR_f5        -5
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is just to use a regex. I prefer `str_extract` from tidyverse.

```r
data %>% str_extract("[^_]+$")
#> [1] "p10" "p9"  "p8"  "p7"  "p6"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>